# Neo4j 2.3.0 Transaction REST endpoint service Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am getting an error while executing the cypher query from REST endpoint

`Message: Failed:      [{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax","message":"Invalid input 'H': expected 'i/I' (line 1, column 39 (offset: 38))\n\"MATCH (n:User) SET n += {properties} WHERE ID(n) = {id} RETURN ID(n) as id, n as user\"\n ^"}]`

Query to REST endpoint : -
"/db/data/transaction/commit"

```
{ 
statement: 'MATCH (n:User) SET n += {properties} WHERE ID(n) = {id} RETURN ID(n) as id, n as user', 
parameters: { id: 185, properties: { lastName: 'Banderas', age: 40 } } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause should be before the SET :

```
MATCH (n:User) WHERE ID(n) = {id}
SET n += {properties}
```